# Customer segmentation or Recommender system?

Tags: machine-learning

I have a dataset containing multiple tables including customer information, customer transactions and list of rewards campaign for customers. I am trying to figure out the customers to run a campaign to the next month and I am confused as to if this is a Recommender system problem (which I am honestly skeptical about as there are no actual products to draw similarities) or a Customer segmentation issue.

Comment: If you want to use the [tag:machine-learning] tag for a question not directly concerning implementation, then consider posting on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), or [Artificial Intelligence](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) instead; otherwise you're probably off-topic. Please choose one site only and do not cross-post to more than one.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Are there some `[easy shortcuts]` somewhat like `[mre]` to help posting the links you just commented? Also, is there a way to vote on closing and migrating to sites other than cross validated?

Comment: I don't know of any shortcuts. I copied the comment from the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info). For closing,  there's no direct method; I suggest a custom reason.